# How to reset the form and login error message in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a formik form where if the user credentials are invalid then it shows an error message. However I want the error message to disappear, i.e, when you click to re-enter the email or password again then the error message should disappear. I also want the form to reset after calling the api. I'd be very grateful if someone can show me where to do this two changes. My form looks something like this:

```
const Login = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [loginError, setLoginError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    const { email, password } = values;
    var body = {
      password: password,
      email: email
    };
    console.log(body);
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body)
    };
    const url = "/api/authenticate";
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      const text = await response.text();
      setSubmitting(false);
      if (text === "redirect") {
        props.history.push(`/editor`);
      } else if (text === "verifyemail") {
        props.history.push({
          pathname: '/verifyOtp',
          state: { email },
        });
      } else {
        setLoginError("Email or Password is incorrect"); //this is the error message
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      //********Using Yup for validation********/

      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string()
          .email()
          .required("Required"),
        password: Yup.string()
          .required("No password provided.")
          .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
          .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
      })}
    >
      {props => {
        const {
          values,
          touched,
          errors,
          isSubmitting,
          handleChange,
          handleBlur,
          handleSubmit
        } = props;
        return (
          <>
            <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
              <CssBaseline />
              <div className={classes.paper}>
                <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
                  <LockOutlinedIcon />
                </Avatar>
                <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                  Sign in
                </Typography>
                <form
                  className={classes.form}
                  onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                  noValidate
                >
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    id="email"
                    value={values.email}
                    label="Email Address"
                    name="email"
                    autoComplete="email"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                  )}
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    required
                    fullWidth
                    name="password"
                    value={values.password}
                    label="Password"
                    type="password"
                    id="password"
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    autoComplete="current-password"
                    className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />

                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password}</div>
                  )}

                  {loginError && (    
                    <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      <span>{loginError}</span>
                    </div>    
                  )}      //want this error message to reset when the user clicks on any of the field to enter the login credentials again

                  <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    disabled={isSubmitting}
                  >
                    Sign In
                  </Button>
                  <Grid container>
                    <Grid item xs>
                      {/* <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link> */}
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item>
                      <Link href="/register" variant="body2">
                        {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
                      </Link>
                    </Grid>
                  </Grid>
                </form>
              </div>
              <Box mt={8}>
                <Copyright />
              </Box>
            </Container>
          </>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

created a sandbox to better understand the problem. enter any email and any password matching the yup validation and click enter then the login error message is shown. I want that to disappear as soon as you click on the textfields  again to re-enter the login info.

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/validated-react-form-gt0xn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use one more state variable and solve this problem.

```
  const [changed, setChanged] = useState(false);
...
      const text = await response.text();
      setSubmitting(false);
      setChanged(false); // after api call, set changed flag false.
      if (text === "redirect") {
...
                    onChange={e => {   // onChange on Inputbox I set the changed flag true.
                      setChanged(true);
                      handleChange(e);
                    }}
...
                  {!changed && loginError && (  // then if changed flag is false show error message.
                    <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
                      <span>{loginError}</span>
                    </div>
                  )}
```

this is my [trial codesandbox url](https://codesandbox.io/s/validated-react-form-vy3xj)